# jquery Tool tip for svg element path

Tags: jquery, svg, tooltip, jquery-svg, jquery-ui-tooltip

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M477.63,166.84l0.51,0.9l0.33,0.14l0.9,-0.21l1.91,0.47l3.68,0.16l0.17,-0.05l1.2,-0.75l2.78,-0.67l1.72,1.05l1.02,0.24l-0.97,0.97l-0.91,2.17l0.0,0.24l0.56,1.19l-1.58,-0.3l-0.16,0.01l-2.55,0.95l-0.2,0.28l-0.02,1.23l-1.92,0.24l-1.68,-0.99l-0.27,-0.02l-1.94,0.8l-1.52,-0.07l-0.15,-1.72l-0.12,-0.21l-0.99,-0.76l0.18,-0.18l0.02,-0.39l-0.17,-0.22l0.33,-0.75l0.91,-0.91l0.01,-0.42l-1.16,-1.25l-0.18,-0.89l0.24,-0.27Z" 
    data-code="BG" 
    fill="#cecdcd" 
    fill-opacity="1" 
    stroke="none" 
    stroke-width="0" 
    stroke-opacity="1" 
    fill-rule="evenodd" 
    id="test" 
    title="this as tool-tip" 
    class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"/>
```

I need that `title` attribute value as tool tip. I tried with the below but nothing happened.

```
$("path", svgRoot).mouseover(function() {
    //var content = $(this).attr("title");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (id != undefined) {
        $(this).tooltip();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you included any tooltip plugins?

Comment: yes i included  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Is it retrieving the `id` properly? It's been awhile, but I think I remember that jquery cannot get `attr`'s of SVG nodes. EDIT: Sorry I just looked at some of my old code and its `addClass` and `removeClass` that don't work on SVG nodes. `attr` should work

Comment: no prob for id i created a object for svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG a tooltip is not represented by a title attribute, you need a `<title>` child element instead.

I.e. while an HTML tooltip looks like this:

```
<p title="title">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

an SVG tooltip would look like this:

```
<text y="50"><title>This is the tooltip</title>This is some text<text>
```

or in your case

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M477.63,166.84l0.51,0.9l0.33,0.14l0.9,-0.21l1.91,0.47l3.68,0.16l0.17,-0.05l1.2,-0.75l2.78,-0.67l1.72,1.05l1.02,0.24l-0.97,0.97l-0.91,2.17l0.0,0.24l0.56,1.19l-1.58,-0.3l-0.16,0.01l-2.55,0.95l-0.2,0.28l-0.02,1.23l-1.92,0.24l-1.68,-0.99l-0.27,-0.02l-1.94,0.8l-1.52,-0.07l-0.15,-1.72l-0.12,-0.21l-0.99,-0.76l0.18,-0.18l0.02,-0.39l-0.17,-0.22l0.33,-0.75l0.91,-0.91l0.01,-0.42l-1.16,-1.25l-0.18,-0.89l0.24,-0.27Z" 
    data-code="BG" 
    fill="#cecdcd" 
    fill-opacity="1" 
    stroke="none" 
    stroke-width="0" 
    stroke-opacity="1" 
    fill-rule="evenodd" 
    id="test" 
    class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element">
    <title>this as tool-tip</title>
</path>
```

You don't need jquery and it won't work for SVG tooltips anyway.